# Create new table with onclick function button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a new table with 1 row and 7 columns that will be displayed on my html page in the  when I click on the button. How do I create this table using the onclick function in Javascript? The  must also have an id. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please first read articles on [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

You should create the table in HTML, and use CSS to set the visibility to collapsed. Then you can change the visibility to visible in your onclick function.